# SSRS second parameter doesnot refresh after input first parameter

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

My SSRS report (2008 version) has two parameters. The first is a textbox receiving input for Supervisor' userid. The second is a drop-down list which depends on the first parameter to show the all the staff name working under the supervisor. After I input a supervisor userid for the first parameter, the second one does not refresh automatically. Then I press enter for the first parameter, an error message shows I have to select a value for the second parameter. My questions is how the second parameter can refresh automatically after I input the first parameter in the textbox.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Can you show us the query for the second parameter?

Comment: SELECT distinct a.[Last_Name]+', '+a.[First_Name] AS Staff_Name
      ,a.[Network_ID] AS Staff_ID
      ,a2.Network_ID as [Manager_ID]
  ,s.STF_NBR as Staff_Nbr
FROM Client_All c 
INNER JOIN DimStaff d ON c.STF_NBR = D.ECMS_Wrkr_ID
INNER JOIN STAFF s ON s.STF_NBR=D.ECMS_Wrkr_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN ADPFile a ON s.FILE_NBR=cast(a.FILE_NBR as nvarchar)
LEFT OUTER JOIN ADPFile a2 ON a2.Position_NBR=a.Supervisor_Position_NBR
WHERE a2.Network_ID =@User_ID
ORDER BY Staff_Name

Comment: @User_id is Int Data type? Also check the independent parameter properties advanced tab if it is set to `never refresh`. I am suspecting the issue is related to data types.

Answer (score 0):

Are both your parameters as well as the **Network_ID** all INTEGERS?

It might work better if your first parameter was also based on a drop-down based on another dataset.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a2.Last_Name + ', ' + a2.First_Name AS Manager_Name, a2.Network_ID as Manager_ID 
FROM Client_All c 
INNER JOIN DimStaff d ON c.STF_NBR = D.ECMS_Wrkr_ID 
INNER JOIN STAFF s ON s.STF_NBR = D.ECMS_Wrkr_ID 
INNER JOIN ADPFile a ON s.FILE_NBR = CAST(a.FILE_NBR AS nvarchar) 
INNER JOIN ADPFile a2 ON a2.Position_NBR = a.Supervisor_Position_NBR
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Both parameters are varchar. For security purpose, the superviser needs to input his Network ID in the text box. But the second parameter(Staffs working under the supervisor) does not refresh after the network ID is entered. I have to press enter to get the second parameter refreshed, however an error message will show 'Please select a value for the staff Name'.

Comment: I think the issue is that when you press ENTER, SSRS tries to run the report instead of moving to the next parameter. Does it work correctly if you enter the Network ID and press TAB to move to parameter 2?

Comment: Hi Hannover Fist, it work correctly if I enter TAB to move to parameter 2. However, after I input the first parameter, the second parameter does not show 'select a value' automatically.

Comment: That's right. It doesn't know when you've finished typing in the first text box so it can't do a cascading prompt in the second. The only way to get it to do this is make the first a drop down, or put a basic web or thick client front end around the report which supports more sophisticated parameter functions. Are you using a text box instead of a drop down for security concerns? Thats not really valid considering you could just 'dictionary attack' it anyway